# Required Field Validator on RadioButton list

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a radiobutton list that the items are dynamically filled.  Now, I have a required field validator that works as expected (if I do a postback, it will ask me to select an item in the radiobuttonlist).

When I click on Next, I clear the radiobuttonlist, and dynamically fill it again with the next set of data. But now, the required field validator's message is already there asking me to select an item (without doing a postback).

Any ideas to make the required field validator message only become triggered if I do a postback?

Thanx

Comment: Do you mean that you want to disable the required field validator client side?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable the required field validator client side validation with the following:

```
ValidatorEnable($("#<%=ReqVal.ClientID%>")[0], false);
```

Replace the `ReqVal` with the id of your RequiredFieldValidator that you want to disable.

Comment: I added this code to the javascript, and had it run on loading the page, but I still get the same validation messages.

Comment: @SulaimanAli I have edited my answer with a possible solution to your problem. I tested it myself for verification. Let me know how it goes.